# Phone Stuck on Samsung Galaxy S2 Screen

Tags: samsung-galaxy-s-2, rom-flashing, unbricking

I have a rooted GT-I9100G. Recently the official JB for France came out, and I wanted to flash it.

Some of the reasons to do so were:

- My phone use to randomly show *charging* even when the charger was not plugged in
- Random reboots would occur
- Had heard the new official firmware was pretty good

So, I went ahead and rebooted to CWM recovery (was running AOKP 4.2). Did a factory and Data wipe, wiped cache, and Dalvik Cache. Now, I've realized I made a mistake by formatting `/system` and rebooting. That shouldn't have been a problem, because it should still boot into Download or Recovery mode (on pressing `Down+Home+Lock` or `Up+Home+Lock` respectively). Yet, when I try entering either the phone gets stuck on the [Samsung Logo screen  :(](https://www.dropbox.com/s/ehr48oyih8hma17/2013-02-11%2014.32.32.jpg)

One thing that is really bothering me is whenever I put in the battery, a couple of seconds later the [battery indicator](https://www.dropbox.com/s/t0166akeufflfjh/2013-02-11%2014.32.03.jpg) shows and stays stuck at that.

Please guys help me out. I don't even have a decent replacement phone for the time-being. :S

Comment: Factory reset and data wipe don't format `/system`. Did you selected *format `/system`* from CWM? If you can't get to either download nor recovery mode there isn't much to do with the phone...

Comment: yes i selected format/system , it didn't occur to me then, but i did it by default cos i do that usually when flashing a new rom through CWM...